# Android SearchView: search again when spyglass key is pressed

Tags: android, searchview, key-events, android-virtual-keyboard

I am using a SearchView widget to search text in a ListView.
When entering text a virtual keyboard opens.
I want to repeat the search when the "spyglass key" is pressed.
**How can I intercept the virtual keyboard key events?**

Note: do not confuse the spyglass key, which is in the virtual keyboard, bottom right, with the spyglass icon in the SearchView widget.

I'll tell you what I tried and therefore I know it does not work:

- onQueryTextChange() on the SearchView
- onKeyListener() on the SearchView
- TextWatcher() on the SearchView
- dispatchKeyEvent() on the ListView

Comment: There's an interesting workaround here: [SearchView listen for IME actions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33385262/383414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I go for.
I haven't found how to get the KeyEVent for the "spyglass key" (I think it is the same as KEYCODE_ENTER), so What I did is to enable the submit button on the SearchView" and I get a call to `onQueryTExtSubmit()` each time it is clicked (method of the onQueryTextListener).

```
    sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.viewer_search);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(searchListener);
    sv.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

And

```
private OnQueryTextListener searchListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // do my stuff
        return true; 
    }

    . . .
```