# SearchView listen for IME actions

Tags: android, searchview

How can I listen for IME actions on a `SearchView`? Since it is not a subclass of `EditText`.

What I want to do is to handle when the user presses the "enter" key on the keyboard **and there is no text entered.**

The problem with there being no text is that `OnQueryTextListener.onQueryTextSubmit()` is only triggered if the user has entered text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about getting EditText of the searchview and using OnEditorAction?

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
int searchViewPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText searchPlateEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchViewPlateId);
searchPlateEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(v.getText().toString())){
                //Text entered
            }
            else {
                //no string
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I suggest putting a `null` check around `searchPlateEditText` in order to protect from future internal design changes, since we are using undocumented code. Since they don't expose their `EditText`, they may change its identifier at any point.

Comment: Works for me as well but just when using `android.widget.SearchView`, did not work with `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`

Answer (score 2):

With `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`, you can use:

```
setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
         return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
         return true
    }
})
```